# How to get selected list view item for context menu click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseclick-event

I need help to get Selected list view item details, when context menu assigned to list view items is clicked.

```
 <ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="GvRowMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image  Source="{Binding IconPath}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <MenuItem 
                        Click="MenuItem_Click"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.RunCommand}" />
```

This is a click event code

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //what needs to de here?
    }
```

I wrote this piece of code in my view model, but it doesnt trigger on execute method

```
RunCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnRunCommand, CanRunCommand);

private void OnRunCommand(object obj)
    {
        // use the object here...
    }

    private bool CanRunCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Let me know, how can I handle this situation. Any examples related to same will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing you methods... you can run an event or you can use a command, but not so much both together.

what you want is to bind the command:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.RunCommand}" />
```

there are many wonderfull sources of info out there... [here is one](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=178).

Comment: I want to do more on clicke event of context menu.

Comment: any advice for below method? private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { //what needs to do here? }

Comment: you can run the Execute method kinda like this:((MyModle)DataContext).RunCommand.Execute( );

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..!
Well, below piece of code worked for me.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)e.Source;
   ContextMenu contextMenu = menuItem.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
   ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
   var x = ((myViewModel)(item.Content)).myModel;
   //'x' gives all required data of list view item
}
```

This is my XAML

```
<ListView.Resources>
   <ContextMenu x:Key="GvRowMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}">
      <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image  Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
               <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding 
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
   </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Just because you can paint a wall by throwing an open paint can at it doesn't mean that's the best way to do it. If I were you I would look at the other answer and research MVVM along with Command binding